# Prevent parent element li being clicked on click on icon i

Tags: html, jquery, css

When I click on any type icon placed on right of li the li is being selected.

How can I avoid this?

Tried with `stopPropagation()` also but was not helpfull. How to avoid clicking on one element effecting other .

```js
$(document).on('click', '#log-menu li', function(event) {
          let getdash = document.querySelectorAll('#log-menu li') 
          getdash.forEach(function(o) {
            if($(o).hasClass("select")){
              $(o).removeClass("select")
            }
          })
          $(this).addClass("select");
        })
```

```css
#log-menu li
  {
    margin-top: 4px;
    display:block;
      font-size: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      /* padding: 1px; */
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #00abc9;
      color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
 #log-menu .select {
    color: white;
    background-color: #01a661;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  #icon1{
  float:right;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="log-info" id="log-menu">
<li>main list
<i class="fas fa-clock" id="icon1" style="font-size:18px;"></i>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: You want add class only when clicking on the `icon` ?

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear to what the final results would be - Please let me know :)

Comment: Add a click handler for the `i` - `$(document).on('click', '#log-menu li i`, function() { ..do stuff..; return false; })`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping  When I select the icon the li element is being selected how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `event Delegation` to check using `event.target.tagName` and see which element was clicked and then you can do your thing seperately on each `ICON` or `LI` clicked.

In your `click` function use this to check if you clicked on `li`

```
//Li clicked
if (event.target.tagName == 'LI') {
  console.log('li clicked')
  //do something when li clicked
}
```

In your `click` function use this to check if you clicked on `ICON`

```
//Icon clicked
  if (event.target.tagName == 'I') {
    console.log('ICON clicked')
    //do something when ICON clicked
  }
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#log-menu li', function(event) {

  //Li clciked
  if (event.target.tagName == 'LI') {
    console.log('li clicked')
    //do something when li clicked
  }

  //ICON clicked
  if (event.target.tagName == 'I') {
    console.log('Icon clicked')

    //Add remove class when ICON clicked
    let getdash = document.querySelectorAll('#log-menu li')
    getdash.forEach(function(o) {
      if ($(o).hasClass("select")) {
        $(o).removeClass("select")
      }
    })
    //target only icons
    $(this).addClass("select");
  }
})
```

```css
#log-menu li {
  margin-top: 4px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  /* padding: 1px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #00abc9;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#log-menu .select {
  color: white;
  background-color: #01a661;
  padding: 2px;
}

#icon1,
#icon2,
#icon3 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<ul class="log-info" id="log-menu">
  <li>main list
    <i class="fas fa-clock" id="icon1" style="font-size:36px;"></i>
  </li>
  <br>
  <li>main list
    <i class="fas fa-clock" id="icon2" style="font-size:36px;"></i>
  </li>
  <br>
  <li>main list
    <i class="fas fa-clock" id="icon3" style="font-size:36px;"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes your approach is correct here..we will get to know whuch element is being clicked..But I wanted something like stoppropagation which will prevent its parent item getting selected on click of child item(in my case <i> tag)

Comment: @kavya so you are not happy with my answer ? That’s exactly what you wanted and Doing what you said in comments earlier - There is NO way in this world that we can use stopPropogation here in your scenario. Let me know :)

Comment: @kavya ....and the parent is not getting clicked in my answer. Event target means something we have really clicked on which means the i OR li either one.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to build the containers in a correct way.

This means inside the `li` you can make a div or a button that has the click callback attached. Next to it you can put the FontAwesome icon with no click callback.

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There're several solutions to your issue. I explain you two of them.

One of them (the one I show you in the below example) is to put the text of your *li* element inside other html element (in the example I put it in a span element), and change the event selector to *#log-menu li span*. In that case maybe you'll have to modify your code in order to get elements that are parents, siblings, etc.

I've modified your css and I put a border rule so you can see the span element doesn't fill the hole space because it has inline display by default.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#log-menu li span', function(event) {
  let getdash = document.querySelectorAll('#log-menu li') 
  getdash.forEach(function(o) {
    if($(o).hasClass("select")){
      $(o).removeClass("select")
    }
  })
  $(this).addClass("select");
})
```

```css
#log-menu li
  {
  border:1px solid red;
    margin-top: 4px;
    display:block;
      font-size: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      /* padding: 1px; */
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #00abc9;
      color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
 #log-menu li span {
 border:1px solid blue;
 }
 #log-menu .select {
    color: white;
    background-color: #01a661;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  #icon1{
  float:right;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="log-info" id="log-menu">
  <li>
    <span>main list</span>
    <i class="fas fa-clock" id="icon1" style="font-size:36px;"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Other solution could be to inspect the element type it's being clicked:

```
$(this).prop('nodeName');
$(this).get(0).tagName;
```

In both cases, "SPAN" should be returned. Now, you'll have to add a *stopPropagation* method in the case you are interested in.